# war file with Cache implementation works fine on grails 2.4.4 but fails on tomcat 7

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, grails, caching

I am using grails 2.4.4 and trying to implement cache in it. 
I have added cache-api.jar in the lib folder and in the build path and have added a maven dependency compile "org.jsr107.ri:cache-ri-impl:1.0.0-RC1". 
When I run the war as grails run-app, the cache works fine. 
But when I deploy the same war on tomcat, it gives me the following exception.

```
[http-apr-9090-exec-2] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResol
ver  - NoSuchMethodError occurred when processing request: [POST] /pharma/login
javax.cache.CacheManager.createCache(Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/cache/configuratio
n/Configuration;)Ljavax/cache/Cache;. Stacktrace follows:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionExcepti
on: Executing action [login] of controller [pharma.PharmaController]  ca
used exception: Runtime error executing action
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecu
tionException: Runtime error executing action
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.cache.CacheManager.createCache(Lja
va/lang/String;Ljavax/cache/configuration/Configuration;)Ljavax/cache/Cache;
        at trident.TridentCache.getCache(TridentCache.java:32)
        at trident.pharma.PharmaService.login(PharmaService.groovy:107)
        at trident.pharma.PharmaController.login(PharmaController.groovy:46)
        ... 3 more
```

What baffles me is the war works fine in grails environment and the cache implementation also works perfectly but the same war when deployed on Tomcat, it throws the above exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing which version of grails, tomcat and jdK were in place is quite difficult to understand what's going on, but looking merely to the exception seems that your Grails implementation and the Tomcat you used have two different versions of the javax.cache.CacheManager class.

hence the missing method...

UPDATE: the package you mentioned org.jsr107.ri:cache-ri-impl:1.0.0-RC1 uses the javax.cache » cache-api    1.0.0-RC1

That particular version has this method signature in CacheManager class

```
  <K, V, C extends Configuration<K, V>> Cache<K, V> createCache(String cacheName,
                                                            C configuration)
  throws IllegalArgumentException;
```

Comment: grails 2.4.4 , tomcat 7.0.61, JDK7

Comment: ok, I added what I found in the library you mentioned. I would recommend checking again the path of the library once it goes into tomcat. make sure the jar is in the correct tomcat/lib or tomcat/webapps/<yourwebapp>/WEB-INF/lib folder and double check the version is still 1.0.0-RC1. one last check could be to get a maven-tree of your project to see if the same library with a different version is already included by some other dependency

Comment: Thanks a ton ... I found the problem in the /WEB-INF/lib .... there was another cache-api-0.9 jar which caused the problem. I removed that jar and it worked just fine. Just wondering why that didn't cause a problem on grails environment though.